# filtered_search api in freshworks CRM not returning custom attributes

Tags: crm, freshworks

I need data from freshworks CRM rest api and I am using `/api/filtered_search/[entity]` api to get data modified between 2 time periods. This query is returning correct data. But the result doesn't include all the attributes of a record as the result from view api `/api/sales_accounts/view/[view_id]`. What should I do to get all attributes of records that are modified between 2 time periods ?

Sample query:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token=XXXXXXX -X POST https://personal-XXXX.myfreshworks.com/crm/sales/api/filtered_search/sales_account?include=owner -d '{ "filter_rule" : [{"attribute" : "updated_at", "operator":"is_in_the_range", "value":["2021-02-10T10:00:00", "2021-02-10T15:00:00"]}] }'
```

Result:

```
{
      "id": 70000227816,
      "name": "Everstage Acc 1",
      "last_contacted": null,
      "last_contacted_mode": null,
      "city": null,
      "state": null,
      "country": null,
      "phone": "1234567890",
      "open_deals_amount": "0.0",
      "won_deals_amount": "0.0",
      "avatar": null,
      "created_at": "2021-02-08T22:46:03+05:30",
      "updated_at": "2021-02-10T12:31:56+05:30",
      "recent_note": null,
      "last_contacted_via_sales_activity": null,
      "last_contacted_sales_activity_mode": null,
      "last_assigned_at": "2021-02-08T22:46:04+05:30",
      "facebook": null,
      "twitter": null,
      "linkedin": null,
      "owner_id": 70000012204
    }
```

Expected Result:

```
{
  "id": 70000227816,
  "name": "Everstage Acc 1",
  "address": "12, abc street, 1st cross, 2nd main",
  "city": null,
  "state": null,
  "zipcode": null,
  "country": null,
  "number_of_employees": 11,
  "annual_revenue": 12,
  "website": null,
  "owner_id": 70000012204,
  "phone": "1234567890",
  "open_deals_amount": "0.0",
  "open_deals_count": 0,
  "won_deals_amount": "0.0",
  "won_deals_count": 0,
  "last_contacted": null,
  "last_contacted_mode": null,
  "facebook": null,
  "twitter": null,
  "linkedin": null,
  "links": {
    "conversations": "/crm/sales/sales_accounts/70000227816/conversations/all?include=email_conversation_recipients%2Ctargetable%2Cphone_number%2Cphone_caller%2Cnote%2Cuser&per_page=3",
    "document_associations": "/crm/sales/sales_accounts/70000227816/document_associations",
    "notes": "/crm/sales/sales_accounts/70000227816/notes?include=creater",
    "tasks": "/crm/sales/sales_accounts/70000227816/tasks?include=creater,owner,updater,targetable,users,task_type",
    "appointments": "/crm/sales/sales_accounts/70000227816/appointments?include=creater,owner,updater,targetable,appointment_attendees"
  },
  "custom_field": {
    "cf_customer_succses_email_id": "customer2@abc.com"
  },
  "created_at": "2021-02-08T22:46:03+05:30",
  "updated_at": "2021-02-10T12:31:56+05:30",
  "avatar": null,
  "parent_sales_account_id": null,
  "recent_note": null,
  "last_contacted_via_sales_activity": null,
  "last_contacted_sales_activity_mode": null,
  "completed_sales_sequences": null,
  "active_sales_sequences": null,
  "last_assigned_at": "2021-02-08T22:46:04+05:30",
  "tags": [],
  "is_deleted": false,
  "team_user_ids": null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of Sales Account using `/api/sales_accounts/view/[view_id]` with sort and sort type as updated_at and desc to get the latest updated records. The filtered search API `/api/filtered_search/[entity]` gives only basic details. Try https://developers.freshsales.io/api/#view_account API for complete attributes per record